# Unable to print via dual band wi-fi

Tags: wireless-networking, router, printer

I used to be able to print to my HP Officejet Pro 8610 printer until I upgraded my wi-fi to using a single dual-band AC2200 Nest router. The printer is connected to wi-fi with a valid IP address (196.168.86.5). I tried removing and then reinstalling the printer to the printer list on my mac. The mac was aware of the printer (it listed the printer in the list of possible devices to add) but when I tried to add it I got the error message:

```
Unable to connect to 'HP Officeject Pro 8610 [1ED6EE]._ipp._tcp.local.' due to an error.
```

When I use the command "arp -a" from my mac I can see the printer:

```
mac-mini-2:~> arp -a
hp1ed6ee.lan (192.168.86.5) at fc:3f:db:1e:d6:f0 on en1 ifscope [ethernet]
epson5b8b9d.lan (192.168.86.36) at 0:26:ab:5b:8b:9d on en1 ifscope [ethernet]
```

I also have an Epson WorkForce 630 printer on this wi-fi network which I can print to. I am able to ping the Epson printer but not the HP printer (I get "Request timeout" messages).

I read on the internet that the problem could be that a printer using the 2.4 GHz band would not talk to a device on the 5 GHz band and indeed the HP printer is on the 2.4 GHz band and my mac is using the 5 GHz band. But the Epson printer also uses the 2.4 GHz band so that cannot be the whole story. Unfortunately, with the Nest router, it is not possible to switch my mac to using the 2.4 GHz band (at least not that I can see). I tried using a 2nd mac and had the same problem.

Comment: Any chance to connect the Printer (I have this particular printer here) by Ethernet? Then it will print regardless of the wireless speed you have. My Laptop is 5 GHz AC and I print from it just fine.

Comment: @John Ethernet is possible but since I have multiple computers I really do want to be able to use wi-fi.

Comment: You can set the Printer up on your network and then any device (computers and phones) can print to it . I do that with my printer (same printer).

Comment: @John Sorry I misunderstood. I was thinking of using ethernet to connect printer to computer. Using ethernet to connect printer to router works.

Comment: Yes for sure, putting the printer on your network will work great.

Answer (score 1):

You can put this HP8610 Printer on your Network using Ethernet. This printer supports Air Print.

Make sure the printer has a static IP address (prevents it from getting lost in a network restart.

Install the HP Printer Drivers on each computer. HP Smart Print (App Store) works fine.

Put the phone driver on your phones and set that up.

Now all Wireless Devices (any speed) will print.

Comment: OK this works. Much thanks. I'm still curious as to why one printer (the Epson) would communicate but the HP would not.

Comment: Arg! Sorry. I got confused by a "phantom printer" on my system. I'm getting the exact same problem with the ethernet connection to the printer...

Comment: That one printer works and another one does not depends (in this case) on the network card and driver

Comment: What you might do is delete all your printer drivers (Control Panel, Devices and Printers) , restart, and set real printers up again. The steps above work reliably for most any printer.

Comment: AirPrint is not something that I believe I can remove and reinstall. But trying to use the HP driver instead of AirPrint gives a different failure mode. With the HP driver I can do the install but then when I try to print I get a "printer is not responding" message. Also the HP Easy Start app is able to see the printer but then the app gives me a "Unable to communicate with the device" error.

Comment: Air Print is a Phone app not a computer app. Do not try to install Air Print on your PC. Instead of HP Easy Start (which I do not like), use HP Smart Print from the Microsoft App Store. Keep PC and Air Print separate.

Comment: I don't have a PC I just have macs and android phones. "AirPrint" (no space) is part of the mac OS for communicating with printers. So far, the only way I can print to the HP at this point is to use USB.

Comment: HP 8610 has a MAC driver.  Download (from HP) and try installing that on your MAC.

Comment: I salute your tenacity on trying to solve this! And I do appreciate it. As for the HP driver, using that does not change anything. One clue is that I cannot connect to the printer from my android phone as well so it is not just a mac problem. Plus I cannot ping the printer.

Comment: In the Printer Panel, network settings, make sure it has a static IP and gateway on your network.

Comment: Yes I had tried that. Unfortunately that had no effect.

Comment: I would see if you can get a friend with a laptop to see if they can ping your printer. I am running out of ideas.

Comment: You and me both. If your friend wants to give it a try it is fine with me.

Comment: You need a local friend in your neighborhood.

Answer (score 0):

On the HP Community Support board an HP rep responded to a query of mine to state:

> "You cannot tweak the printer to work with the 5GHz network, the only
> way out is to replace the printer."

Also

> "Almost all the new printers support dual-band but check before you
> make a purchase."